# A grey band about 5px at the bottom of the navigation controller iOS Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

[image: The arrow points to the grey band]

Hello all,

I have a UINavigationController in which I am presenting a view controller  modally using UIModalPresentationPageSheet style. I see a grey band at the bottom of the view controller (The image shows the arrow pointing at the band). I am not able to figure out what this band is, I want to get rid of it. As part of my investigation, I added a Green color border to the navigationcontroller's view and Red color to the viewcontroller's view, but the grey bar is appearing outside it. Any idea what this could be?

Thank you!

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
will remove shadow from bottom. its that

Comment: Not working.. I have subclassed the UINavigationController and using this customer class i am presenting a controller modally.

Comment: its looking another layer, behind the view layer. please check your preview layers

Comment: How do I check preview layers?

Answer (score 0):

when you run the app , then there is print icon on bottom . before that give different color to each view, it will help you to see exactly different layer.
you slider to see each layer

[image]